# Woocommerce Product child category from current parent category

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, categories, product

I am trying to show the WooCommerce product child category for the corresponding parent category. I have entered the product as following:

[image: Product Category details that I entered]

I am using the following code segment that displays the parent category list:

```html
<?php
$IDbyNAME = get_term_by('name', $parent_cat_NAME, 'product_cat');

$product_cat_ID = $IDbyNAME->term_id;

   $args = array(
       'hierarchical' => 1,
       'show_option_none' => '',
       'hide_empty' => 0,
       'parent' => $product_cat_ID,
       'taxonomy' => 'product_cat'
   );

    $categories = get_categories($args);

    foreach ($categories as $category) {
        echo $category->name;
    }
?>
```

That is working well. Now I want to modify my code segment to display output as below:

```
Album
    English Songs
        Modern Songs
        Pop
        Rock
```

How can i do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have got the solve of this problem to show the category, Sub-category and product in woocommerce wordpress is as following,

```html
<?php
$taxonomy = 'product_cat';
$orderby = 'name';
$show_count = 0; // 1 for yes, 0 for no
$pad_counts = 0; // 1 for yes, 0 for no
$hierarchical = 1; // 1 for yes, 0 for no
$title = '';
$empty = 0;

$args = array(
'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
'orderby' => $orderby,
'show_count' => $show_count,
'pad_counts' => $pad_counts,
'hierarchical' => $hierarchical,
'title_li' => $title,
'hide_empty' => $empty
);
?>

<?php
$all_categories = get_categories( $args );
foreach ($all_categories as $cat)
{

if($cat->category_parent == 0)
{
$category_id = $cat->term_id;
$thumbnail_id = get_woocommerce_term_meta( $cat->term_id, 'thumbnail_id', true );
$image = wp_get_attachment_url( $thumbnail_id );
echo "<ul class='category'><li>".$cat->name;
$args2 = array(
'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
'child_of' => 0,
'parent' => $category_id,
'orderby' => $orderby,
'show_count' => $show_count,
'pad_counts' => $pad_counts,
'hierarchical' => $hierarchical,
'title_li' => $title,
'hide_empty' => $empty

);

$sub_cats = get_categories( $args2 );
if($sub_cats)
{

foreach($sub_cats as $sub_category)
{
echo "<ul class='subcategory'>";
if($sub_cats->$sub_category == 0)
{
echo "<li>".$sub_category->cat_name;

?>
<?php
/*echo "<pre>";
print_r($sub_category);
echo "</pre>";*/

$args = array( 'post_type' => 'product','product_cat' => $sub_category->slug);
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
echo "<ul class='products'>";
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); global $product; ?> <li>
<a href="<?php echo get_permalink( $loop->post->ID ) ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr($loop->post->post_title ? $loop->post->post_title : $loop->post->ID); ?>">
<?php the_title(); ?>
</a></li>
<?php endwhile; ?>
</ul>
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>

<?php
}
else
{
echo "</li></ul></li>";
}
echo "</ul>";
}
}
else
{
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'product', 'product_cat' => $cat->slug );
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
echo "<ul class='products'>";
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); global $product; ?> <li>
<a href="<?php echo get_permalink( $loop->post->ID ) ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr($loop->post->post_title ? $loop->post->post_title : $loop->post->ID); ?>">
<?php the_title(); ?>
</a></li>
<?php endwhile; ?>
</ul></li></ul>
<?php wp_reset_query();
}
}
else
{
echo "</li></ul>";
}
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all create an array of all the items

```
$all = array(
        0 =>array(
                "id"=> 1,
                "name"=> "A",
                "parent_id"=> 0
            ),
         1 =>array(
                "id"=> 2,
                "name"=> "B",
                "parent_id"=> 1
            ),
         2 =>array(
                "id"=> 3,
                "name"=> "C",
                "parent_id"=> 1
            ),
         3 =>array(
                "id"=> 4,
                "name"=> "D",
                "parent_id"=> 2
            ),
        4 =>array(
                "id"=> 5,
                "name"=> "E",
                "parent_id"=> 0
            ),
    );
```

Use this function to make recursive n times array from your items

```
function makeMenu($items, $parentId)
{
    $menu = array_filter($items, function ($item) use ($parentId) {
        return     $item['parent_id'] == $parentId;
    });
    foreach ($menu as &$item) 
    {
        $subItems = makeMenu($items, $item['id']);
        if (!empty($subItems)) 
        {
            $item['sub_menu'] = $subItems;
        }
    }
    return $menu;
}
```

Call function `makeMenu($yourArray,$parentID)`

```
makeMenu($all,0); ////parent ID is 0 by default while calling..
```