# Import product categories parent / child relation in another way than ID in WooCommerce Rest API

Tags: wordpress, import, woocommerce-rest-api, hierarchical, taxonomy-terms

I'm loading a quite extensive feed through the rest API.

The importation runs well, but I only have one problem.

The supplier defines the relation between parent and child by id provided in the feed.

However WooCommerce does not let me define the ID for the categories since it's read only.
When I try to define it using the ID from the JSON the import fails.

Not only the hierarchy of parent / child but also the products refer to the suppliers chosen ID which is included in the JSON.

Could anyone please be so kind to point me in the right direction?

Any help is very much appreciated.

When the import failed I commented the ID part and the import worked.
I tried multiplying the ID by 10 in order to avoid using existing ID's but afterwards I read that WooCommerce does not allow you to define category ID's if I understood correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the ID, you can use the "slug" field. The "slug" can be defined manually and is unique for each category.

Comment: And can you use the slug field to define parent and child hierarchy for category?

Comment: Yes, you can use the slug field to define the parent-child hierarchy for categories.

* https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69197365/add-parent-and-child-categories-from-json-to-woocommerce-via-rest-api
* https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37630991/woocommerce-product-child-category-from-current-parent-category

Comment: Okay I have been trying to implement this but I can't get it to work.

My supplier provides me with ID and Parent ID for the categories.

The products use these same ID's in order to assign categories.

Isn't there any way to force the WooCommerce category ID to be writable instead of read only?

Comment: In WooCommerce, the category ID is read-only, and you cannot manually define it. WordPress automatically generates the ID for each category in the database.

But you should be able to use the slug field to associate the products that refer to the supplier's chosen ID with the correct category.

However, if you still need to force the category ID to be writable, then you might need to modify WooCommerce core files, which is not recommended as it can lead to issues with future updates and can potentially break your site.

Comment: Alternatively, you can get the product and category information in a CSV file. Then, use the WooCommerce Product CSV Import Suite plugin to import them onto your site. During the import process, make sure to map the correct category ID.